# Вычисление вероятности наступления события

Tags: разработка-игр, математика, теория-вероятностей

Есть некоторое количество действий. Например, 3. Каждое из них может произойти с какой-либо вероятностью. Как можно вычислить, какое из действий должно произойти в данный момент?

Например:

```
Действие 1: 40%
Действие 2: 50%
Действие 3: 10%
```

Допустим, получаем случайное число от 1 до 100, и на основе этого выбираем одно из действий. Если `число = 30`, то останавливаемся на 1 действии. Если `число = 45`, то 1 не подходит, переходим на 2 и так далее. На 3 действие таким образом мы никогда не попадем (от 1 до 10 всегда будет выбираться 1 действие).

Допустим, если процентные соотношения верны (не `10, 10, 10` и не `40, 50, 30`, например), то мы можем расположить вероятности наступления соответствующих действий на прямой от 1 до 100. В моем примере это будет выглядеть так:

```
Действие 1: 40% (1-40)
Действие 2: 50% (40-90)
Действие 3: 10% (90-100)
```

И получившееся случайное число проецировать на один из этих диапазонов.

Правильно мыслю или нужен принципиально другой подход?

Comment: Всё правильно, так и надо.

Comment: Да, если разбить участок 1-100 по Вашим числам и генерировать случайное число, получите нужное распределение сл.величины ЕСЛИ исходные случайные числа распределены равномерно. Если не уверены - сделайте свой ГСЧ, идей много

Comment: Вторая идея - сделайте массив из 10 эл-тов. Один со значением 3, четрыре - 2, пять - 1. И выбирайте эл-т массива по случайному индексу (0-9)

Comment: @DNS, хорошая идея, но для простых ситуаций, не для тех, где вероятности не будут кратными 10.

Comment: @nup, пишу в рамках поставленного вопроса... Вторая идея упростит код - можно просто использовать двойное индексирование в одно действие `action[variant[random(10)]]`, хотя потребуется некоторая подготовка массива. При более сложных вариантах размер массива увеличится. Но и также увеличится тот `switch`, который будет проверять диапазоны. Просто альтернатива - на выбор ТС